# Data from jQuery callback is failing to compare

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to make a "sign in status" thing.

Here is a summary of what is happening.

User fills our field and jQuery request is sent.
Credentials are validated.
Screen displays a welcome message.

So I can get the welcome message sent back to me if the credentials are valid (or error if credentials are false), but here is where the issue resides...

I am having a really difficult time storing anything in PHP as a global variable using my only jQuery (no included file) approach... So my workaround was to take the passed message (Let's just say when credentials are valid, I pass back something like "X" or "1"), and then when the data comes back in the jQuery, I put an if statement in the callback, but it isn't working.

I know that the data being passed is matching what is being compared, and i've tested many different things to pass back, but the comparison is not being done.

Perhaps it isn't possible to do things like if statements in a jQuery callback, but also maybe I'm doing something wrong.

HTML:

```
<label>Sign In</label>
<br>
<label>Username</label>
<input type="text" id="name1"> 
 <label>Password</label>
<input type="text" id="pass1"> 
<br>
<button type="submit" id="button2">Sign In</button> 
<div id = "xx1">Status: Offline</div>
   <div id = "xx2"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#button2").click(function(){
            var name1=$("#name1").val();
            var pass1=$("#pass1").val();
            var key = "signIn";
            $.ajax({
                url:'rpc.php',
                method:'POST',
                data:{
                    name1:name1,
                    pass1:pass1,
                    key:key

                },
               success:function(data){
                   if(data === '1')
                   {
                      document.getElementById('xx1').innerHTML = "Status: Online";
                   }
                   document.getElementById('xx2').innerHTML = data;
                   //var p = data;


               }
            });
        });
    });
```

(xx2 is updating by the way)

Lastly, relevant bits of my rpc.php:

```
else if($_POST['key'] === "signIn")
{
$name1=$_POST['name1'];
$pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];

if($name1 !== "" && $pass1 !== "")
{


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM whatever";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($name1 === $row["username"])
    {
        $UNTrue = true;
        if (password_verify($pass1, $row['password'])) {
            $PassTrue = true;
        }

    }


}
} else {
//echo "0 results";
}




if($UNTrue === true && $PassTrue === true)
{
    echo "1";


$conn->close();
}
else
{

    echo "<p  align=center style = 'color:#ba261b'>(Incorrect Username or Password) </p>";

    $conn->close();
}

}
else
{

   echo "<p  align=center style = 'color:#ba261b'>(Please Fill Required Fields) </p>";

$conn->close();
}
}
```

So data is "1" in this scenario, as displayed to my via xx2, and xx1 remains as "Status: Offline".

I'm wondering if I have to store the data in a JavaScript variable first, and then later somehow referencing it again ASAP.

The other option would be to figure out how to use PHP global variables without file inclusion.

Comment: have you tried using console.log to verify data is in fact `1`?

Comment: Yeah, @imvain2 That's what the xx2 div is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible even though you're echoing "1", it's getting interpreted as a number? Assuming the `data` response you get in the success callback is literally just what your PHP script echoes, that's the first thing that jumps out to me, since `(1 === "1")` is `false`.

Comment: I've tried "echo true;" from php which is definitely = 1 (and displayed as 1 in my xx2 div), but still no luck :(